# apply lambda condition on multiples if else condition

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda

```py
df['expens'] = df.apply(lambda z : z['total_bill'] * 2  if z['total_bill'] < 10 ,axis = 1)
```

I want to apply the  lambda expression using the if condition and create new column variable `df['expens']`
under the condition if `df['total_bill] is < 10`

I tried the above  the python syntax but is throws an error "invalid syntax"

Comment: What do you expect the function to do if `z['total_bill']` is *not* less than 10?

Comment: `df.loc[df['total_bill'] < 10, 'expens'] = df['total_bill'] * 2`

Comment: A conditional expression *must* include values for when the condition is both true and false. If you only want to apply the function to a subset of the column, you need to filter the column first, then apply an unconditional function to the result.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], which has tips like how to write a good title.

Comment: My point is that how to use lambda function to get the above  . I am aware of the .loc function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the condition during indexing, not in the lambda if you only want to apply the function to those rows for which the condition is true. Also no need for a lambda if just multiplying in pandas.

```py
df.loc[df["total_bill"]<10, "expens"] = df["total_bill"] * 2
```

**NB.** it is possible to have a condition in a lambda with the ternary operator `lambda x: x * 2 if x < 10 else x` but not useful in this case.

Comment: def yelp(price):
    if price < 10:
        return '$'
    elif price >= 10 and price < 30:
        return '$$'
    else:
        return '$$$'                                                                                               
                                                                                                                          df['Expensive'] = df['total_bill'].apply(yelp)   ,how to use lambda to obtain yelp function